# Mobile Website Lose Focus To Drop Keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs, mobile

I have a mobile web site that I'm testing with a Motorola Android phone.   I have a search box so when you click the text input which is the search box, the keyboard slides up.   The issue is when I submit with the "arrow" on the keyboard, the focus/cursor stays inside the text input box while the action of the form is performed, so the keyboard stays there.   It is an Angular JS function that is called with the 'enter' key on the keyboard.

What I need to do is lose focus on that text input box so the keyboard drops out of the way when they submit the form.   I've been trying things with jQuery but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

After you submit the form, try to blur the input field:

```
$("#myElement").blur(); //works
```